# Android Studio 3.0 generates flat dependencies tree so how do I read it

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Android Studio 3.0 generates flat dependency tree. So how can I figure out which dependency has a transitive dependency I'm looking for ?

For instance there is transitive dependency to support lib 25.3.1 somewhere in my dependencies. Executing `androidDependencies` task I figured out that some library is using `customtabs:25.3.1` but I can not figure out which one because my dependencies tree looks like this:

```
alphaDebug
alphaDebugCompileClasspath - Dependencies for compilation
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2@aar
+--- :NyheterCore:lib (variant: debug)
+--- /Users/oleg/Projects/AndroidStudio/Innocode/apps/nyheter-app/NyheterCore/lib/libs/ExpiringMap.jar
+--- com.android.databinding:adapters:1.3.1@aar
+--- com.android.databinding:library:1.3.1@aar
+--- com.android.databinding:baseLibrary:3.0.0@jar
+--- :SwipeToCloseActivity:swipetoclose (variant: debug)
+--- :MediaStorage:lib (variant: debug)
+--- :Skeleton:skeletonlib (variant: debug)
+--- :UtilsLib:lib (variant: debug)
+--- :MediaChooser:lib (variant: debug)
+--- com.trello:rxlifecycle-components:0.6.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:design:26.0.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.android.support:transition:26.0.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:26.0.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-fragment:26.0.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:26.0.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:26.0.1@aar
+--- net.openid:appauth:0.7.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:customtabs:25.3.1@aar
+--- com.trello:rxlifecycle:0.6.1@aar
+--- com.jakewharton.rxbinding:rxbinding:0.4.0@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:26.0.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.0.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-compat:26.0.1@aar
+--- com.android.support:support-annotations:26.0.1@jar
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.2@aar
+--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.8@jar
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.3.0@jar
+--- com.github.tony19:timber-loggly:1.0.1@jar
+--- com.github.tony19:loggly-client:1.0.3@jar
+--- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0@jar
+--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.1@jar
+--- com.github.JakeWharton:ViewPagerIndicator:2.4.1@aar
+--- :cxense-insight-2.0.2:@aar
+--- :cxense-content-1.0.1:@aar
+--- com.google.dagger:dagger:2.11@jar
+--- javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0@jar
+--- junit:junit:4.12@jar
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.3.0@jar
+--- com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.3.0@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.8.1@jar
+--- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1@aar
+--- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.0@jar
+--- com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4@jar
+--- no.schibstedpayment:SPiD-Android:1.3.10@aar
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.1.4-3@jar
+--- com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:2.2.2@aar
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2@aar
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.3.11@aar
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.3.9@aar
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.2@aar
+--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.3.13@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- javax.inject:javax.inject:1@jar
+--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3@jar
+--- com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2@jar
+--- com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19@jar
+--- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.8.1@jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0@jar
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.0.2@jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.jakewharton.timber:timber:2.5.1@jar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl-license:11.4.2@aar
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-v4-impl-license:11.4.2@aar
\--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.13.0@jar
```

Answer (score 5):

I hit the exact same issue, pretty frustrating. I found the only solution was to run `gradle dependencies` or `gradle dependencyInsight` from an outside terminal. For example:

```
./gradlew :your-module-name:dependencies
```

Or if you know which dependency you want to look at, like in your case:

```
./gradlew :your-module-name:dependencyInsight --configuration=alphaDebugCompileClasspath --dependency=customtabs
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 2):

`./gradlew app:androidDependencies` generates flat dependencies

`./gradlew app:dependencies` generates tree so use this one.

Comment: When I do that, it says,'Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-5.4.1-all.zip' and thereafter goes crazy by outputting dots endlessly.

Comment: try offline mode

Comment: I tried a different approach and it worked. Went to gradle tab on the side panel, clicked on execute task button on top, selected app module and ran the configuration. Gave the desired result exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this command:

```
./gradlew -q dependencies mymodulename:dependencies
```

This should show the dependencies tree

Answer (score 0):

`gradlew app:dependencies` worked for me (in the terminal pane of the android studio).
without "./" before the command.

Answer (score -2):

Update to Android Studio 3.1 fixes the problem